# Google's Scholar bibtex not working

Tags: bibtex

I'm not sure why I see no references shown ... I'm copy pasting from google scholar.

I've already done:

- pdflatex bibtex pdflatex pdflatex
- latex bibtex latex

Here's my code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
     \section{intro} % (fold)
     \label{sec:intro}
       \nocite{*}
     % section intro (end)
     \bibliography{refs}
    \end{document}
```

and the bib file

```
@book{sommerville2003engenharia,
  title={Engenharia de software},
  author={Sommerville, Ian and Melnikoff, Selma Shin Shimizu and Arakaki,Reginaldo and de Andrade Barbosa, Edilson},
  volume={6},
  year={2003},
  publisher={Addison Wesley S{\~a}o Paulo}
}
@book{pressman2016engenharia,
  title={Engenharia de Software-8{\textordfeminine} Edi{\c{c}}{\~a}o},
  author={Pressman, Roger and Maxim, Bruce},
  year={2016},
  publisher={McGraw Hill Brasil}
}
```

I've tried both BEAMER and ARTICLE classes, and nothing shown ... any help?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) you haven't spacified any bibtex style. The bibtex run should give you an error about no style specified

Comment: Here is an example of how that bibtex error can look like (as I ran it through your MWE): `This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016)
The top-level auxiliary file: imf.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file imf.aux
(There was 1 error message)`

Comment: Hey, I have code that doesn't have any style specified, and worked great ... but it worked thanks.

Comment: Then I'd like to see that code. If it is using a custom class or package, then those may set a specific bibtex style, or perhaps you are not even using bibtex, perhaps you are using `biblatex`. Details matters.

Comment: Here -
 https://gist.github.com/ceciliassis/5b151738b21e724c12defc1272c334cf
I've compiled with `bibtex`

Comment: And what do we have in live 204? The wanted `\bibliography{style}`  BTW: `center` is not a macro, it is an environment so use it with `\begin/end`, the `t1enc` is not needed as it it the same as your `fontenc` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the MWE that just worked for me.  You need to add the requested style to the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 \section{intro} % (fold)
 \label{sec:intro}

  This is my work, I am citing \cite{pressman2016engenharia} and \cite{sommerville2003engenharia}

 % section intro (end)
 \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
 \bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

This compiles as,
[image]

Comment: I don't understand the difference between your answer and the one suggested in the comment by ''daleif''.

Comment: @RaajaG it is the same thing. Austin just added an example of how a style is added

Comment: Maybe I should have provided my solution as a comment?  But either my "answer" or his comment should work for you.